# The most lightweight button implementation in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, button, memory-management, sprite, cpu-usage

Since button is one of the most popular GUI components `this question becomes hot` when we talk about `memory usage`. Especially when you have `tons of buttons` in your application.

So how you can implement a button that uses `minimum CPU and memory resources` and yes, acts like normal button with mouse up, down and hand pointer behavior implemented. **Label text** is also required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have tonnes of buttons with text and graphics, using the least amount of RAM and processing power, you should be using Bitmaps.

This gets a lot more complicated and involves your own preparation of the following:

1. A font in the form of a sprite sheet.
2. Classes that manage rendering text onto a Bitmap using that sprite sheet.
3. Bitmaps don't respond to MouseEvents, so you'll need to architect your own system for managing mouse input on the Bitmaps.

Firstly, lets take a look at the base memory consumption for some of the DisplayObjects that you would think we would be best using. This is our testing method:

```
function ram(type:Class):void
{
    trace(getSize(new type()));
}
```

And this is the test:

```
ram(Sprite); // 408
ram(Shape); // 236
ram(TextField); // 1316
```

In your case, drawing 1000 buttons would result in over 1,724,000 bytes of memory being used.

Now let's look at what we will be using:

1. 1x Bitmap acting as a Canvas that holds all buttons: 236 bytes.
2. 1x BitmapData representing the initial state of every button.
3. 1x BitmapData representing the rollover state of every button.
4. 1x BitmapData storing our text as a sprite sheet for use by all buttons.

Each `BitmapData` will be quite large in memory consumption, and varies greatly depending on its content. But the trick here is that we only use *one* and refer to its content for every button that we want to draw.

I've set up a small amount of code to get you started. You still need to implement a click manager which loops over all the buttons and works out which is most relevant to trigger a click, as well as rendering the text on the buttons.

Here's the Button class:

```
public class BitmapButton
{

    private var _text:String;
    private var _position:Point = new Point();


    public function BitmapButton(text:String)
    {
        _text = text;
    }


    public function render(canvas:BitmapData, font:BitmapData, state:BitmapData):void
    {
        canvas.copyPixels(state, state.rect, _position);

        // Use font argument to render text.
        // For you to implement.
    }


    public function get position():Point{ return _position; }

}
```

And here's the class that will manage rendering those buttons:

```
public class ButtonCanvas extends Bitmap
{

    private var _fontSprite:BitmapData;
    private var _baseState:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 30, false, 0xFF0000);
    private var _overState:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 30, false, 0x00FF00);
    private var _buttons:Vector.<BitmapButton> = new <BitmapButton>[];
    private var _checkRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle();


    public function ButtonCanvas(width:int, height:int)
    {
        bitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, true, 0x00000000);

        // Replace with actual loaded sprite sheet.
        _fontSprite = new BitmapData(1, 1);
    }


    public function add(button:BitmapButton):void
    {
        _buttons.push(button);
    }


    public function render():void
    {
        if(stage === null) return;

        bitmapData.lock();
        for each(var i:BitmapButton in _buttons)
        {
            _checkRect.x = i.position.x;
            _checkRect.y = i.position.y;
            _checkRect.width = _baseState.width;
            _checkRect.height = _baseState.height;

            if(_checkRect.contains(mouseX, mouseY))
            {
                // Use roll over style.
                // Need to implement depth check so you can't roll over buttons
                // that fall behind others.
                i.render(bitmapData, _fontSprite, _overState);
            }
            else
            {
                i.render(bitmapData, _fontSprite, _baseState);
            }
        }

        bitmapData.unlock();
    }


    public function get buttons():Vector.<BitmapButton>{ return _buttons; }

}
```

And a small test:

```
var canvas:ButtonCanvas = new ButtonCanvas(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
addChild(canvas);


for(var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var button:BitmapButton = new BitmapButton("Hello");
    button.position.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    button.position.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    canvas.add(button);
}


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, update);
function update(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    canvas.render();
}

canvas.render();
```

Now that you've read all of that, I'll point out that it's *really* unlikely you need to anywhere near this extreme, unless you have some type of game that revolves around buttons and buttons are actually particles that get generated every frame in the 100's. Using a standard Sprite + TextField is perfectly fine in almost all cases.

Comment: In your case, drawing 1000 buttons would result in over 1,724,000 bytes -- why? If I use only textfield it will be 1,316,000 But man, this is very interesting. Could you please explain more about getSize() function?

Comment: @ZuzEL Because you have to define a new Sprite and TextField for every button. In my sample, you only need to define a new `BitmapButton` instance, which is extremely lightweight. Also, `getSize()` tells you how much memory an object is using.

Comment: I don't need Sprite in my example

Comment: @ZuzEL OK sure, but a TextField is very heavy both for memory consumption and rendering difficulty.

Comment: Yes, but could you tell me more about `getSize()` function? How it is implemented? Where did you get it?

Comment: @ZuzEL Err it's an inbuilt function...

Comment: @ZuzEL http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sampler/package.html#getSize()

Comment: thank you. Finnaly I got it

Answer (score 1):

One of the traditional patterns is using `Sprite + TextField`

Adobe recommends using Shape instead of Sprite (when it makes sense):

> a Sprite object is a display object container, whereas a Shape object is not. For this reason, Shape objects consume less memory than Sprite objects that contain the same graphics.

It would be great to use Shape, and we can do it, but we can not add TextField on it.

Now lets look at TextField inheritance chain:

> TextField:   InteractiveObject -> DisplayObject -> EventDispatcher -> Object

We can *observe that a TextField object is much lighter than a Sprite object* - **wrong**. Using only TextField will be lighter than using `TextField + Sprite`. I came up with this decision:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.filters.BevelFilter;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.ui.MouseCursor;

public class Button extends TextField 
{
    private static const MOUSE_UP:Array = 
    [new BevelFilter(2, 45, 0xEEEEEE, .7, 0x444444, .7, 1, 1)];

    private static const MOUSE_DOWN:Array = 
    [new BevelFilter(2, 225, 0xEEEEEE, .7, 0x444444, .7, 1, 1)];

    private static const TEXT_FORMAT:TextFormat = 
    new TextFormat('Verdana', 12, 0xDDDDDD,
    null, null, null, null, null, 'center');

    public function Button(label:String, color:int = 0x166488) 
    {
        width = 80;
        height = 20;
        background = true;
        backgroundColor = color;
        selectable = false;
        defaultTextFormat = TEXT_FORMAT;

        text = label;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseRollOver);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onMouseRollOut);
        onMouseUp();
    }

    private function onMouseRollOut(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.AUTO;
    }

    private function onMouseRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;
    }

    private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        filters = MOUSE_DOWN;
    }

    private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent = null):void 
    {
        filters = MOUSE_UP;
    }
    //kill method
}
```

[image: Generated button]

This code draws nice lightweight button **BUT** I can not adjust vertical position of a text label so height of this button depends of font-size. Another issue is that I cann't move the text label a bit down-right when somebody clicks it.

**Any ideas will be appreciated.**

Comment: `We can observe that a TextField object is much lighter than a Sprite object.` That's completely incorrect. A `Sprite` uses 408 bytes in memory whereas a `TextField` uses 1316.

Answer (score 1):

> We can observe that a TextField object is much lighter than a Sprite object. That's completely incorrect. A Sprite uses 408 bytes in memory whereas a TextField uses 1316

Yes TextField will consume way more memory.

I would create the label text in a graphics program and create a sprite menu class.

TextField is not really lightweight but a pretty powerful class. If you want user input then TextField is the way to go.

Avoid any of the buttons built into the Flash library and just start simple and build functionality on the sprite class.

If you really want to optimize your interface, reduce the event handlers and any sort of transparency. This might just be good Flash advice in general but often overlooked.

Make a function that gets called every frame, tick();, think();, update(); something like this. Add a single event handler to the main class and within that call your update() function within the menu elements.

Adding a dozen event handlers to your menu elements is not only cumbersome but unsightly.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say a `sprite` with the `buttonMode` property set to `true` for the "hand pointer" and then functions to handle the `ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT` MouseEvents.

Comment: This is the most popular way to do it, thanks! But why do you need to listen ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT events if you already have buttonMode set to true? I think you meant MOUSE_UP and MOUSE_DOWN. Do you?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requirement for "mouse up, down and hand pointer". The Rolls are to see a graphical change in the button when you mouse over the button. I guess it's functionally the same as just the hand pointer to indicate that the mouse is over a button, but it's prettier :)